# JSon Deserializing getting type

Tags: c#, .net, json

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Account { Name = "test" }, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
        Console.Out.Write(json);
        while (true) 
        {
        }
    }
}

class Account {
    public String Name;
}
```

Hey, im trying to get into Json. I want to deserialize an object. I want to get the type information out of the string. So when i deserialize i want json to recognize the type by itself without specifying it. Is that possible?

Best Regards,
Brian

Comment: I tried to get the information with "string.contains(...)" but the problem is, when several different types are saved.
Edit: I also tried to get the type with .getType() but then i just get a JSonObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.net unfortunately can't infer the type by the json, but if you would like to operate on Json objects dynamically, check out the JToken, JObject, and JArray types from the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace. You can read Json from a path like so

```
var myObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
var someObject = myObject["myOtherObject"]["otherThing"];
var myString = (string) someObject["theString"];
```

I find this part of Json.net very useful and I hope it helps you :)